# How do I type alias a templated struct

Tags: generics, rust

I can alias a struct like this:

```rust
struct DummyStruct {}
use DummyStruct as MyStruct;
```

But when it comes to templated struct:

```rust
struct TemplatedStruct<T> {
    v: T
}
use TemplatedStruct::<i32> as AnotherStruct;
```

I got error:

```
8 | use TemplatedStruct::<i32> as AnotherStruct;
  |                      ^ expected identifier
```

How do I fix it to alias a templated struct?

Comment: This is what [`type`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.type.html) is for. You `use` the thing, then `type` it as you wish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`use` does not create aliases, it imports and when used with `as`, renames imports.

To create a [type alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#creating-type-synonyms-with-type-aliases), use `type`.

```rs
type AnotherStruct = TemplatedStruct<i32>;
```

Note that `TemplatedStruct` is a generic struct. Rust does not use the term "template".

Answer (score 4):

When you use `as` in a `use` declaration, that's not strictly speaking a type alias - rather you are just importing the item using another name.

An actual type alias looks like this:

```rust
type MyStruct = DummyStruct;
```

You can specify generics here:

```rust
type AnotherStruct = TemplatedStruct::<i32>;
```

See also:

- [Type aliases](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/type-aliases.html) in the Rust reference
- [Use declarations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/use-declarations.html) in the Rust reference